# GL_STACK_OVERFLOW (0x503) error Cocos2d

Tags: memory-management, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, removechild

So I have it set up so when the characters health is < 100 (for testing purposes) it  stop the scene and goes to the game over scene.

```
if (playerDataManager.playerHealth < 100) {
   [[CCDirector sharedDirector]  replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:3 scene: [GameLogic scene]]];
}
```

However when the players health drops below 100, it goes to the new scene, but the FPS drops dramatically from 60 to 5.

I get a list of `OpenGL error 0x0503 in -[EAGLView swapBuffers]` then it stays frozen like that for about 40 seconds, then the FPS unfreeze and goes back out to 60 and I get a list of `2012-07-13 10:37:50.234 Tilegame[93513:10a03] cocos2d: removeChildByTag: child not found!`

Then I can continue with the app like normal, going back to the main menu, starting a new game, then recreate the error.

```
#import "HelloWorldLayer.h"
#import "Menu.h"
#import "SimpleAudioEngine.h"
#import "LogCabinMap.h"
#import "LogShedMap.h"
#import "SaveData.h"
#import "pauseM.h"
#import "Player.h"
#import "GameLogic.h"

CCSprite *player;
CGPoint newPos;
int joyDegrees;

// HelloWorldLayer implementation
@implementation HelloWorldLayer

@synthesize tileMap = _tileMap;
@synthesize background = _background;
@synthesize buildings = _buildings;
@synthesize meta = _meta;
@synthesize player = _player;
@synthesize foreground = _foreground;
@synthesize numCollected = _numCollected;
@synthesize hud = _hud;


-(void) animateEnemy:(CCSprite*)enemy {
    //speed of the enemy
    ccTime actualDuration = .2;
    id actionMove;
    int distanceFromPlayer = ccpDistance(player.position, enemy.position);

    if (distanceFromPlayer < 200) { //Check whether enemy can "see" Ninja before moving towards him.
        //rotate to face the player
        CGPoint diff = ccpSub(player.position,enemy.position);
        float angleRadians = atanf((float)diff.y / (float)diff.x);
        float angleDegrees = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(angleRadians);
        float cocosAngle = -1 * angleDegrees;
        if (diff.x < 0) {
            cocosAngle += 180;
    }
        enemy.rotation = cocosAngle;

    actionMove = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:actualDuration
                                                   position:ccpMult(ccpNormalize(ccpSub(player.position,enemy.position)),10)];

} else {
            actionMove = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:actualDuration
                                     position:ccpMult(ccpNormalize(ccpSub(player.position,enemy.position)),0)];
}

id actionMoveDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self
                                         selector:@selector(enemyMoveFinished:)];
[enemy runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil]];
}

// callback. starts another iteration of enemy movement.
- (void) enemyMoveFinished:(id)sender {
     CCSprite *enemy = (CCSprite *)sender;

    [self animateEnemy: enemy];
}



-(void)addEnemyAtX:(int)x y:(int)y {
    CCSprite *enemy = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"enemy1.png"];
    enemy.position = ccp(x, y);
    [self addChild:enemy];
    [self animateEnemy:enemy];
}

-(void)setViewpointCenter:(CGPoint) position {

    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    int x = MAX(position.x, winSize.width / 2);
    int y = MAX(position.y, winSize.height / 2);
    x = MIN(x, (_tileMap.mapSize.width * _tileMap.tileSize.width) 
        - winSize.width / 2);
    y = MIN(y, (_tileMap.mapSize.height * _tileMap.tileSize.height) 
        - winSize.height/2);
    CGPoint actualPosition = ccp(x, y);

    CGPoint centerOfView = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
    CGPoint viewPoint = ccpSub(centerOfView, actualPosition);
    self.position = viewPoint;

}

-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init] )) {
        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadEffect:@"pickup.caf"];
        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadEffect:@"hit.caf"];
        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadEffect:@"move.caf"];
        //[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"TileMap.caf"];
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
        self.tileMap = [CCTMXTiledMap tiledMapWithTMXFile:@"TileMap.tmx"];
        self.background = [_tileMap layerNamed:@"Background"];
        self.foreground = [_tileMap layerNamed:@"Foreground"];
        self.buildings = [_tileMap layerNamed:@"Buildings"];
        self.meta = [_tileMap layerNamed:@"Meta"];
        _meta.visible = NO;

        CCTMXObjectGroup *objects = [_tileMap objectGroupNamed:@"Objects"];
        NSAssert(objects != nil, @"'Objects' object group not found");
        //NSMutableDictionary * padPoints = [objects objectNamed:@"pad"];
        NSMutableDictionary * padPoints;
        SaveData * SaveDataManager = [SaveData sharedSaveDataManager];

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i ++) {
            for (padPoints in [objects objects]) {
                if ([[SaveDataManager.padArray objectAtIndex: i] intValue] == 1 ){
                    if ([[padPoints valueForKey:@"pad"] intValue] == i){
                        int x = [[padPoints valueForKey:@"x"] intValue];
                        int y = [[padPoints valueForKey:@"y"] intValue];
                        self.player = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"man.png"];
                        _player.position = ccp(x+16,y+16);
                        //[self addChild:_player];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // iterate through objects, finding all enemy spawn points
    // create an enemy for each one
    NSMutableDictionary * spawnPoints;
    for (spawnPoints in [objects objects]) {
        if ([[spawnPoints valueForKey:@"Enemy"] intValue] == 2){
            int x = [[spawnPoints valueForKey:@"x"] intValue];
            int y = [[spawnPoints valueForKey:@"y"] intValue];
            [self addEnemyAtX:x+=16 y:y+=64];

        }
    }


    player = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"man.png"];

    player.position= _player.position;
    [_tileMap addChild:player z: 0];

   // [self addChild:player z:10];

    [self setViewpointCenter:player.position];
    [self addChild:_tileMap z:-1];
    [self scheduleUpdate];
    }
return self;
}


- (CGPoint)tileCoordForPosition:(CGPoint)position {
    int x = position.x / _tileMap.tileSize.width;
    int y = ((_tileMap.mapSize.height * _tileMap.tileSize.height) - position.y) /           _tileMap.tileSize.height;
    return ccp(x, y);
}

-(void)setPlayerPosition:(CGPoint)position {
    Player * playerDataManager = [Player playerSaveDataManager];
    CGPoint tileCoord = [self tileCoordForPosition:position];
    int tileGid = [_meta tileGIDAt:tileCoord];
    int x = player.position.x;
    int y = player.position.y;
    if (tileGid) {
        NSDictionary *properties = [_tileMap propertiesForGID:tileGid];
        if (properties) {
            NSString *collision = [properties valueForKey:@"Collidable"];
            if (collision && [collision compare:@"True"] == NSOrderedSame) {
                //[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"hit.caf"];
                if (joyDegrees > 45 && joyDegrees < 135){

                    player.position = ccp(x,y-1);
                }
                if (joyDegrees > 135 && joyDegrees < 225){

                    player.position = ccp(x+1,y);
                }
                if (joyDegrees > 225 && joyDegrees < 315){

                    player.position = ccp(x,y+1);
                }
                if ((joyDegrees > 315 && joyDegrees < 360) || (joyDegrees > -1 && joyDegrees < 45)){
                                       player.position = ccp(x-1,y);
                }
                return;
            }
            NSString *collectable = [properties valueForKey:@"Collectable"];
            if (collectable && [collectable compare:@"True"] == NSOrderedSame) {
                [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"pickup.caf"];
                [_meta removeTileAt:tileCoord];
                [_foreground removeTileAt:tileCoord];
                self.numCollected += 1;
                [_hud numCollectedChanged:_numCollected];
                playerDataManager.playerHealth -= 10;
            }
            NSString *Gate = [properties valueForKey:@"Gate"];
            if (Gate && [Gate compare:@"1"] == NSOrderedSame) {
                SaveData * SaveDataManager = [SaveData sharedSaveDataManager];
                //[SaveDataManager.padArray removeAllObjects];
                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i ++) {
                    [SaveDataManager.padArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
                }
                [SaveDataManager.padArray replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];  
                //[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[LogCabinMap scene]];
                [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:[LogCabinMap scene]];
            }
            if (Gate && [Gate compare:@"2"] == NSOrderedSame) {
                SaveData * SaveDataManager = [SaveData sharedSaveDataManager];
                //[SaveDataManager.padArray removeAllObjects];
                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i ++) {
                    [SaveDataManager.padArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
                }
                [SaveDataManager.padArray replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
                //[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[LogShedMap scene]];
                [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:[LogShedMap scene]];
            }


        }
    }

    //[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"move.caf"];
    player.position = position;
   }

-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     return YES;

}


-(void) update:(ccTime)deltaTime {
    [self setPlayerPosition:newPos];
    [self setViewpointCenter:player.position];
}



// on "dealloc" you need to release all your retained objects
- (void) dealloc
{
    // in case you have something to dealloc, do it in this method
    // in this particular example nothing needs to be released.
    // cocos2d will automatically release all the children (Label)
    self.tileMap = nil;
    self.background = nil;
    self.foreground = nil;
    self.buildings = nil;
    self.meta =nil;
    self.player = nil;
    player = nil;
    self.hud = nil;
    // don't forget to call "super dealloc"
    [super dealloc];
}
@end


@implementation HelloWorldHud
@synthesize background;
@synthesize background2;
@synthesize health;
@synthesize baseScaleFactor;

+(CCScene *) scene
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
    HelloWorldHud *layer = [HelloWorldHud node];

    // add layer as a child to scene

    [scene addChild: layer z:2];
    HelloWorldLayer *hud = [HelloWorldLayer node];    
    [scene addChild: hud z:1];

    //layer.hud = hud;
    // return the scene
    return scene;
}

-(void)initJoystick {                         
    SneakyJoystickSkinnedBase *joystickBase = [[[SneakyJoystickSkinnedBase alloc] init]     autorelease];        
    joystickBase.backgroundSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"JoyB.png"];                     
    joystickBase.thumbSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"JoyS.png"]; 
    joystickBase.joystick = [[SneakyJoystick alloc] initWithRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 128, 128)]; 
    joystickBase.position = ccp(55, 55);
    [self addChild:joystickBase];
    leftJoystick = [[joystickBase.joystick retain] autorelease];  
}

-(void) update:(ccTime)deltaTime { 
    Player *playerDataManager = [Player playerSaveDataManager];
    CGPoint scaledVelocity = ccpMult(leftJoystick.velocity, 100); 
    CGPoint newPosition = ccp(player.position.x + scaledVelocity.x * deltaTime, player.position.y + scaledVelocity.y * deltaTime); 

    if (leftJoystick.velocity.x == 0 && leftJoystick.velocity.y == 0 ){
        if (!playerDataManager.standStill) {
            [player stopAllActions];
            playerDataManager.walkUp = FALSE;
            playerDataManager.walkDown = FALSE;
            playerDataManager.walkRight = FALSE;
            playerDataManager.walkLeft = FALSE;
            playerDataManager.standStill = TRUE;
            [player runAction:playerDataManager.standAction];
        } 
    }
    if (leftJoystick.degrees > 45 && leftJoystick.degrees < 135){
        if (!playerDataManager.walkUp) {
            [player stopAllActions];
            playerDataManager.walkUp = TRUE;
            playerDataManager.walkDown = FALSE;
            playerDataManager.walkRight = FALSE;
            playerDataManager.walkLeft = FALSE;
            playerDataManager.standStill = FALSE;
            [player runAction:playerDataManager.walkUpAction];
        } 
    }
    if (leftJoystick.degrees > 135 && leftJoystick.degrees < 225){
        if (!playerDataManager.walkLeft) {
            [player stopAllActions];
            playerDataManager.walkUp = FALSE;
            playerDataManager.walkDown = FALSE;
            playerDataManager.walkRight = FALSE;
            playerDataManager.walkLeft = TRUE;
            playerDataManager.standStill = FALSE;
            [player runAction:playerDataManager.walkLeftAction];
        } 
    }
    if (leftJoystick.degrees > 225 && leftJoystick.degrees < 315){
        if (!playerDataManager.walkDown) {
            [player stopAllActions];
            playerDataManager.walkUp = FALSE;
            playerDataManager.walkDown = TRUE;
            playerDataManager.walkRight = FALSE;
            playerDataManager.walkLeft = FALSE;
            playerDataManager.standStill = FALSE;
            [player runAction:playerDataManager.walkDownAction];
        } 
    }
    if (((leftJoystick.degrees > 315 && leftJoystick.degrees < 360) &&     (leftJoystick.velocity.x != 0 && leftJoystick.velocity.y != 0 )) || ((leftJoystick.degrees > -1 && leftJoystick.degrees < 45) && (leftJoystick.velocity.x != 0 && leftJoystick.velocity.y != 0 ))){
        if (!playerDataManager.walkRight) {
            [player stopAllActions];
            playerDataManager.walkUp = FALSE;
            playerDataManager.walkDown = FALSE;
            playerDataManager.walkRight = TRUE;
            playerDataManager.walkLeft = FALSE;
            playerDataManager.standStill = FALSE;
            [player runAction:playerDataManager.walkRightAction];
        } 
    }

    float scaleFactor = playerDataManager.playerHealth/baseScaleFactor; 
    health.scaleX = playerDataManager.playerHealth/1;
    newPos = newPosition;
    joyDegrees = leftJoystick.degrees;
    if (playerDataManager.playerHealth < 100) {
       [[CCDirector sharedDirector]  replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:3 scene: [GameLogic scene]]];
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector]  replaceScene: [GameLogic scene]];
    }
}



-(void) scroll:(ccTime)dt 
{
    //move 30*dt px vertically
    if (background.position.y<background2.position.y){
        background.position = ccp(background.contentSize.width/2, background.position.y - 225*dt);
        background2.position = ccp(background2.contentSize.width/2,     background.position.y+background.contentSize.height);
    }else{
        background2.position = ccp(background2.contentSize.width/2, background2.position.y- 225*dt);
        background.position = ccp(background.contentSize.width/2, background2.position.y+background2.contentSize.height);

    }

    //reset offscreen position
    if (background.position.y <-background.contentSize.height/2)
    {
        background.position =     ccp(background.contentSize.height/2,background2.position.y+background2.contentSize.height);
    }else if (background2.position.y < -background2.contentSize.height/2)
    {
        background2.position = ccp(background2.contentSize.height/2,     background.position.y+background.contentSize.height);
    }
}


-(id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        CGSize size = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;


        background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"rain.png"];
        background2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"rain.png"];

        [background.texture setAliasTexParameters];
        [background2.texture setAliasTexParameters];

        //position background sprites
        background.position =     ccp(background.contentSize.height/2,background.contentSize.width/2);
        background2.position = ccp(size.width,0);

        //schedule to move background sprites
        //[self schedule:@selector(scroll:)];

        //adding them to the main layer

        //[self addChild:background z:-1];
        //[self addChild:background2 z:-1];

        [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"GUI.plist"]; 
        CCSpriteBatchNode *GUISpriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"GUI.png"];
        [self addChild:GUISpriteSheet];

        CCSprite * healthBar = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"bar.png"];
        CCSprite * cap = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"cap.png"];
        CCSprite * endCap = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"endcap.png"];
        health = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"red.png"];
        healthBar.anchorPoint = ccp(0,1);
        health.anchorPoint = ccp(0,1);
        cap.anchorPoint = ccp(0,1);
        endCap.anchorPoint = ccp(0,1);
        healthBar.position = ccp(1 , size.height);
        healthBar.scaleX = 25;
        cap.position = ccp(0 , size.height);
        int width = [healthBar boundingBox].size.width;
        endCap.position = ccp(width , size.height);
        health.position = ccp(1, size.height-2);
        baseScaleFactor = width;
        health.scaleX = baseScaleFactor;
        [self addChild:healthBar];
        [self addChild:cap];
        [self addChild:endCap];
        [self addChild:health];
        CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
        label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"0" dimensions:CGSizeMake(50, 20)
                                  alignment:UITextAlignmentRight fontName:@"Verdana-Bold" 
                                   fontSize:18.0];
        label.color = ccc3(0,0,0);
        int margin = 10;
        label.position = ccp(winSize.width - (label.contentSize.width/2) 
                             - margin, label.contentSize.height/2 + margin);
        [self addChild:label];

        CCMenuItemFont * pause = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Pause" target:self selector:@selector(pause:)];       
        CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems: pause, nil];
        pause.position = ccp(206,142);
        [self addChild:menu];

        CCSprite *pix = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"pix.png"];
        pix.position = ccp(size.width/2, size.height/2);
        //pix.scale = 50000;
    [self addChild:pix z:1];
        //[pix runAction:[CCTintTo actionWithDuration:10 red:255 green:0 blue:0]];
        //[pix runAction:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:15 scale:500]];

        pix.color = ccc3(255, 255, 255); 
        [self scheduleUpdate];



        [self initJoystick];

    }
    return self;
}


- (void)numCollectedChanged:(int)numCollected {
    [label setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", numCollected]];
    // [label setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", score]];
}

- (void) pause: (id) sender
{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:[pauseM scene]];

}

- (void) dealloc
{

    self.background = nil;
    self.background2 = nil;
    self.health = nil;
    self.meta =nil;
    player = nil;

    // don't forget to call "super dealloc"
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Above is the .m scene that is running when the problem occurs and below is the GameLogic.m

```
#import "GameLogic.h"
#import "Player.h"
#import "Menu.h"

@implementation GameLogic

+(id) scene
{
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    GameLogic *layer = [GameLogic node];

    [scene addChild: layer];

    return scene;
}


+(id) gameLogicSaveDataManager {
    static id gameLogicSaveDataManager = nil;
    if (gameLogicSaveDataManager == nil) {
        gameLogicSaveDataManager = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return gameLogicSaveDataManager;
}


-(id) init
{

    if( (self=[super init] )) {
        CCSprite *bg = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bg.jpg"];
        bg.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
        id fadeIn = [CCFadeIn actionWithDuration:3];

        [self addChild:bg];
        [bg runAction: fadeIn];   

        CCLayer *menuLayer = [[[CCLayer alloc] init] autorelease];
        [self addChild:menuLayer];
        CCMenuItemImage *home = [CCMenuItemImage
                                          itemFromNormalImage:@"bg.jpg"
                                          selectedImage:@"bg.jpg"
                                          target:self
                                          selector:@selector(home:)];
        CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems: home, nil];
        home.position = ccp(0,0);
        [menuLayer addChild: menu];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) home: (id) sender
{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[Menu scene]];

}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: do you have a very complex scene ? how deep is your Node Tree ? it think more than 11 Levels will make a problem.

Comment: try to remove CCTransitionFade transition. just replace scenes. the lag can be because of rendering two scenes at the same time and fading also will take time.

Comment: 40 seconds freezed is not that normal

Comment: What is a node tree? And the scene I'm going to is just a CCMenu with one button to go back to the main menu

Comment: I tried removing the CCTransitionFade and now it just completely crashes.

Comment: I also tries replacing it with a different scene and got the same results. So I think that the problem lies within its .m/.h file and no the one i switch to.

Comment: Actually I fixed some of my dealloc issues and now the problem only happens when I try to go to the GameLogic scene. Is there limit to how many scenes, layers, or classes you can have in cocos2d?

Comment: Okay now it works without the transition... Why is that? Whats the point of having transitions if you can't use them?

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL error 0x503 means `GL_STACK_OVERFLOW`, it means you are pushing too many things onto the opengl stack.

I see several instances of `pushScene` in your code, but no instances of `pop` anything anywhere. You cannot just keep pushing things indefinitely without popping them, or you will get this error.

Comment: those push scenes are only called when the player is on the specified tiled. It then pushes the new scene (new map e.g. a house) then the player goes back out of the house it pops the scene. Bringing it back to the original scene.

Comment: I'd suggest logging every time you push and pop to make sure you're doing what you think you are. Something is overflowing opengl's stack. @stenger96

Comment: The problem only occurs when I try to use the fade transition, any thoughts?

Comment: No, I don't know anything about cocos, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

We need to what is currently running in your scene, how it has been allocated and how it is released. We also need to know the same information for the new loaded scene GameLogic. Edit your question and add these data.

Comment: How do I make the code scrollable in my post so its not really long?

Comment: the code you posted is already scrollable. I am not familiar with tiled maps, are you sure they are autoreleasable? I guess it would be better if you post the GameLogic scene code as well

Comment: Okay, will do. And yeah I figured it out after.